# What is the name for the types of assets used in games like "Brotato"?

Tags: sprites, vector-art

What type of assets are used in games like "Brotato"?

[Brotato steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1942280)

[Video of gameplay](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1942280/videos/)

Would these be called vector graphics or are they just really smooth looking sprites? I'm interested in any search terms I could use to learn more about this type of art and how it is made. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please include essential illustrations into the question itself. Links rot.

Comment: You can learn more about Brotato specifically by checking out its modding options on its Steam Workshop page - based on a quick glance, it looks like it's using sprites.

Answer (score 2):

Vector graphics are not a type of art style. Vector graphics just means it can be scalabled with no loss of quality.

The art style looks similar to that of Binding of Isaac (Edmund McMillen), but in the end, it is some kind of pixel graphic. Search terms like `hd smooth pixel grafic` will turn up sprites in a similar kind. You can always add more descriptors like `hd dark rpg smooth pixel grafic` to get more specific results.

As for how they are made? Either you hire an artist (and give some example arts for the style you want), search an asset store or go to the drawing board yourself.

Creating art is a skill for itself. You can always start with some simple pixel art (search for a tutorial on the video platform of your choice) and improve from there with training. There is not really a shortcut for making great looking art besides practise and even more practise.

Comment: I don't think a pixel art tutorial would be a good guide to reproducing this style. Most pixel art focuses on working with a visible square grid, whereas these sprites are high-res enough to show smooth curves without visible pixelation. Is there a particular reason to use the spelling "grafic" over "graphic" in searches?

Comment: True, but when someone has no knowledge at all on how to create game art assests, simple pixel art (not even needed to look good) is easier to create than a smooth good looking high resolution image. And with enough zoom, even the hd image is almost pixel art.

Comment: There are many simple/placeholder art styles - box-art, Paint doodles, pencil drawing photoed and trimmed, MidJourney, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the information, Zibelas. After searching around for smooth pixel art I am seeing a lot of information about tools where you can take a pixelated image and upscale it and do anti-aliasing to get the smoother look that I was asking about in the post. This has helped me to get started learning more about it, so thanks again.